# node.js login with passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am implementing a basic login system with passport but I keep receiving this error when I login with the correct credentials:

Express
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'passport' of undefined

However works fine when I login with wrong credentials by redirecting back to login page. Help?

app.js

```
 //dependencies
 var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('./auth');

var app = express();
server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
// all environments
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
....
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')({src: path.join(__dirname, 'public')}));
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 ......
 //routes

 app.get('/login', routes.login);
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
failureRedirect: '/login',
successRedirect: '/user'
}));

 app.get('/user', routes.user);
```

index.js

```
    exports.login = function(req, res) {
        res.render('login', {title: 'Log in'});
    };

     exports.user = function(req, res) {
   if (req.session.passport.user === undefined) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {

       res.render('user', {title: 'Welcome!',
            user: req.user
        })
    }
    };
```

auth.js

```
     var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        if (username === 'admin' && password === 'lynda') {
            return done(null, {username: 'admin'});
        }

        return done(null, false);
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
    done(null, {username: username});
});

module.exports = passport;
```

Comment: When do you set `req.session.passport`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the session declaration, so req.session is undefined

```
app.use( express.cookieParser() );
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'my secret', cookie: { maxAge : 1200000 } }));
```

also, you seem to be mixing up the requires:

```
var passport = require('./auth');
```

I would change this to:

```
var auth = require('./auth');
```

to avoid confusion with the passport library

Comment: When I put that line i get this error: 500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined

Comment: Nvm I added app.use( express.cookieParser() ); b4 that line and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Perfect - I've added a not about the requires which might make things easier to understand too

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a session, so you can't do  if (req.session.passport.user === undefined) ...

You probably didn't set the session after login

Comment: How would I set a session?  Is there middlewear i need to install? Thanks